# Read CSV - The process cannot access the file

Tags: python

When reading or writing CSV-files sometimes the file can´t be accessed:

`The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file`

I want my code to retry the reading/writing until it works.

Here is a draft how i would make a while loop until the file could be read.

But how can i test if "READING_DID_WORK"? Is tehre a way to test if the task was successfull? Or should i just test if FILE = List?

```
timeout = time.time() + 120 #seconds

bool = True
while bool == True:
time.sleep(0.5) # sleep for 500 milliseconds
    if time.time() > timeout:
        syncresult="timeout"
        break
    with io.open(SlogFilePath,"r", encoding = "utf-16(LE)") as File:    
        FILE = File.read().splitlines()
        if READING_DID_WORK:
            bool = False
        else:
            bool = True

OUT = FILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the extra boolean (`bool` is a very bad variable name anyway) and you don't need `READING_DID_WORK`, just rely on the `OSError` that will be raised.

A simple wrapper function:

```py
import time

...

def read_file_with_retry(file_name, encoding="utf-16(LE)"):
    while True:
        try:
            with open(file_name, encoding=encoding) as f:
                file_content = f.readlines()
        except OSError:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            return file_content
```

To avoid a case of infinite loop, it is suggested to implement a max-retry mechanism:

```py
import time

...

def read_file_with_retry(file_name, encoding="utf-16(LE)", max_retries=5):
    retry = 0
    while True:
        try:
            with open(file_name, encoding=encoding) as f:
                file_content = f.readlines()
        except OSError:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            retry += 1
            if retry > max_retries:
                raise
        else:
            return file_content
```

Comment: Thank you very much DeepSpace, i appreciate your explanation and advice! Is there any way to induce a OSError so i can test the code?